# Getting separate positive/negative colors for heatmap using plot_ly function in R

Tags: r, plotly, heatmap

I have a matrix with following values.

```
heatrix = matrix(c(-32.28, 1, -3.57, 14.75, 26.62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 26, -69.2, -59, -5.12, -14.94, 0),nrow = 4,ncol=4,byrow = T)
```

I want to make a heatmap where positive values in the heatrix are green and negatives are red.  "0" values could be white or any other arbitrary number.

```
p <- plot_ly(
x = c("0-25", "25-50", "50-75", "75-100"),
y = c("0-25", "25-50", "50-75", "75-100"),
z = heatrix, type = "heatmap",
colors = colorRamp(c("red", "green"))
```

)

This gives me green squares with negative values so it is harder to tell which values are above or below 0 easily.  How do I make the scale that I'd like using plot_ly?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know the solution using `plot_ly()`, but when I want heatmap with actual values instead of z-score I'm using the solution which I found here some time ago. Maybe it will be useful for you too.

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
heatrix = matrix(c(-32.28, 1, -3.57, 14.75, 26.62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 26, -69.2, -59, -5.12, -14.94, 0),nrow = 4,ncol=4,byrow = T)
dat <- heatrix %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  rownames_to_column('Var1') %>%
  gather(Var2, value, -Var1) %>%
  mutate(
    Var1 = factor(Var1, levels=1:10),
    Var2 = factor(gsub("V", "", Var2), levels=1:10)
  )

ggplot(dat, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
```

[image]

Yes we can change thick labels of both axes:

```
new_scale <- c("0-25", "25-50", "50-75", "75-100")
```

Then add layers in `ggplot()` function

```
ggplot(dat, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels= new_scale) + # <-
  scale_x_discrete(labels= new_scale) + # <-
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked very well! Very good solution.  IS there a way to label the values of each axis?  Like c("0-25", "25-50", "50-75", "75-100") instead of c("1", "2", "3", "4")? +1

Comment: Solution modified^^